# Blight Druid Archetype & Domains?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, archetype

So, I haven't played Pathfinder for an extremely prolonged amount of time, and I'm building a Druid character (I've never built one before, so excuse me if this is question with an obvious answer.) I've picked the Blight Druid archetype for campaign reasons, but I'm confused about the domain aspect of it. Can I select both an archetype and domain?

Answer (score 4):

## The archetype [blight druid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo---druid-archetypes/blight-druid) changes what domains are available to such a [druid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid)

The blight druid gains the ability *either* to gain a [familiar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/familiar) like a [wizard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard#TOC-Arcane-Bond-Ex-or-Sp-) *or* to pick a domain (gaining its benefits) from an expanded list ([Air](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/air-domain), [Animal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/animal-domain), [Darkness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/darkness-domain), [Death](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/death-domain), [Destruction](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/destruction-domain), [Earth](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/earth-domain), [Fire](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/fire-domain), [Plant](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/plant-domain), [Water](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/water-domain), [Weather](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/weather-domain), and the [animal and terrain domains](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo---druid-archetypes/animal-and-terrain-domains)).

That's because the druid special ability [nature bond](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid#TOC-Nature-Bond-Ex-) says, in part, that

> At 1st level, a druid forms a bond with nature. **This bond** can take one of two forms. The first is a close tie to the natural world, **granting the druid one of the following cleric domains: Air, Animal, Earth, Fire, Plant, Water, or Weather. Druids also have access to a set of Animal and Terrain Domains.** When determining the powers and bonus spells granted by this domain, the druid's effective cleric level is equal to her druid level. A druid that selects this option also receives additional domain spell slots, just like a cleric. She must prepare the spell from her domain in this slot and this spell cannot be used to cast a spell spontaneously.
>
> The second option is to form a close bond with an animal companion. A druid may begin play with any of the animals listed in Animal Choices. This animal is a loyal companion that accompanies the druid on her adventures.

Emphasis mine. And then the [blight druid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo---druid-archetypes/blight-druid) arcehtype *changes* the special ability nature bond, saying that

> A blight druid may not bond with an animal companion, but may either call a familiar as a wizard of her druid level or select from the Darkness, Death, and Destruction domains in addition to those normally available.

Note that nothing (except, obviously, the GM) prevents a blight druid from having an animal companion from another source (such as the granted power of the [Animal domain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/animal-domain)).

Comment: A pleasure to serve. :-). Easier to understand.  +1.

Comment: You could add that some of the animal and terrain domains grant a familiar, making just choosing a familiar not the best option, even if you want one. But +1 even without that.

Comment: @Umbranus Do any of those blight druid domains *really* grant the ability to summon—rather than an animal companion—a *familiar* though? (The answer's final 'graph already mentions getting an animal companion from the domain.)

Comment: The blight druid states " select from the Darkness, Death, and Destruction domains **in addition to those normally available**." And among those normally available are the animal and terrain domains among which are the eagle, the frog, serpent and the monkey domains which grant a hawk, toad, viper and monkey familiar, respectively

Comment: @Umbranus Excellent. Thank you. Will update when I've a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, druids get access to one domain from a specific list of domains, or an animal companion from their Nature Bond class feature:

> **Nature Bond (Ex)**
>
> At 1st level, a druid forms a bond with nature. This bond can take one
>   of two forms. The first is a close tie to the natural world, granting
>   the druid one of the following cleric domains: Air, Animal, Earth,
>   Fire, Plant, Water, or Weather. Druids also have access to a set of
>   Animal and Terrain Domains. When determining the powers and bonus
>   spells granted by this domain, the druid's effective cleric level is
>   equal to her druid level. A druid that selects this option also
>   receives additional domain spell slots, just like a cleric. She must
>   prepare the spell from her domain in this slot and this spell cannot
>   be used to cast a spell spontaneously.
>
> The second option is to form a close bond with an animal companion. A druid may begin play with any of the animals listed in Animal Choices. This animal is a loyal companion that accompanies the druid on her adventures.

The Blight Druid archetype changes the Nature Bond class feature:

> **Nature Bond (Ex)**
>
> A blight druid may not bond with an animal companion, but may either
>   call a familiar as a wizard of her druid level or select from the
>   Darkness, Death, and Destruction domains in addition to those normally
>   available.

This feature replaces your animal companion with a familiar, or if you choose to take a domain instead, it adds those three domains to the cleric domains normally available to a druid.

Comment: Druids can take a domain instead of a companion by default

Comment: @LeesusFreak Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact, you have access to three additional domains in addition to the set you could normally choose from (the three being granted by the archetype are the Darkness, Death, and Destruction domains)